# Using foreign keys on the same model, but on two different fields

Tags: django

If this question is stupid I'm sorry, but I couldn't really find anything useful on Google.

So I have a model made up of two fields.

I want to create a model with some other fields, but two of them should be the ones from the previous one. Is there any way to obtain this?

Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import date

# Create your models here.
class CORMeserii(models.Model):
    CodCOR = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    MeserieCor = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Oferta(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cor = models.ForeignKey(CORMeserii, max_length=25, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meserie = models.ForeignKey(CORMeserii, max_length=50, to_field='MeserieCor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataSolicitare = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    denumireMeserie = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    locuri = models.IntegerField()
    agentEconomic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adresa = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dataExpirare = models.DateField()
    experientaSolicitata = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    studiiSolicitate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    judet = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    localitate = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    emailContact = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    rezolvata = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cor
```

I thought this might work, but I get these errors:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import date
from .validators import validate_file_size

# Create your models here.
class CORMeserii(models.Model):
    CodCOR = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    MeserieCor = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Oferta(models.Model):
    solicitant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cor = models.ForeignKey(CORMeserii, max_length=25, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meserie = models.ForeignKey(CORMeserii, max_length=50, to_field='MeserieCor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dataSolicitare = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    denumireMeserie = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    locuri = models.IntegerField()
    agentEconomic = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    adresa = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    dataExpirare = models.DateField()
    experientaSolicitata = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    studiiSolicitate = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    judet = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    localitate = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    telefon = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    emailContact = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    rezolvata = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.cor
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need both fields in Oferta?

Comment: I think you don't understand what a `ForeignKey` is. When you define a fk, it's a pointer to the other model, so if you have an instance of `Oferta`, let's say `oferta`, then `oferta.cor` is the **instance** related to it (it's an object of type `CORMeserii`). `oferta.cor.CodCor` gives you one field, `oferta.cor.MeserieCor` gives you the other field. You shouldn't define two fks to the same model on `Oferta`, unless they are really different and have a different purpose.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because in the Oferta model (which means Offer, and Meserie means Job, and CodCOR is a code assigned for each type of job - just so you understand better what's happening) the possible values should be the ones from the CORMeserii model.

Comment: @dirkgroten yeah, that's what I thought. I explained in the comment before my logic. What do you think?